# Python neural network weights

Tags: python, python-3.x, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I'm introducing myself into Neural Networks and it's the first time I'm trying to program one. Hope you can help me out:

So lets say I want to program a generic MLP, which means I can change the layers_size of itself at any moment.
 For example, layers_size = [2,2,1] or layers_size = [5,40,40,3] [...,...,...].

My problem is I don't know how to save the random generated weights going to each neuron into a 2D matrix. Can somoneone help me out?

I'm trying with something like this:

```
weights = []
length = len(layers_size)
#appreciate loop starting in 1 since you dont need 
#weights #in the entry layer

#runs layers_size times - 1
for i in range(1, length):
#Gives the amount of neurons for each layer
for j in range(0, layers_size[i]):
    #Get the amount of neurons from the previous layer to 
    # the actual neuron so it saves layers_size[i] - 1 
    # numWeights for the actual neuron...
    weights[i][j] = random...
```

But I don't feel like this being the best idea to save my MLP weights nor it's working for me.

Could you guys help me out?

Thanks in advice.

PS: tensorflow nor keras can't be used.

Comment: Using numpy to save your matrix can save you time

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/python

import numpy as np

layers_size = [5,40,40,3]

weights = []
length = len(layers_size)
#appreciate loop starting in 1 since you dont need 
#weights #in the entry layer

#runs layers_size times - 1
for i in range(0, length):
    weights.append([])
#Gives the amount of neurons for each layer
    for j in range(0, layers_size[i]):
        #Get the amount of neurons from the previous layer to 
        # the actual neuron so it saves layers_size[i] - 1 
        # numWeights for the actual neuron...
        weights[i].append(np.random.randint(1, 101))

print(np.array(weights))
```

Output:

```
[list([81, 53, 53, 55, 71])
 list([34, 75, 12, 14, 9, 69, 56, 1, 98, 73, 14, 82, 60, 52, 13, 7, 14, 9, 5, 8, 24, 61, 75, 52, 82, 91, 67, 75, 22, 77, 84, 71, 83, 77, 56, 99, 94, 49, 100, 84])
 list([45, 44, 71, 89, 16, 22, 41, 36, 42, 38, 53, 4, 25, 53, 16, 81, 47, 70, 9, 88, 81, 27, 66, 91, 97, 53, 41, 20, 20, 15, 77, 38, 60, 1, 30, 17, 55, 51, 33, 30])
 list([43, 60, 17])]
```

Comment: Hi Conner! Thats not exactly what i was looking for, consider that in neural networks each neuron of a layer connects to a neuron of the next layer through a weight. Being this said what I meant in my problem is: having a [2,2,1] layers_size means theres going to be a 2x2 weights between 1st and 2nd layers to get connected. And 2x1 weights between 2nd and 3rd layer to be connected. Now this should be generic. I.e. [5, 40, 40, 3] would be 200 (5 weights for each neuron of the second layer), (1600, 40 for each in between 2nd and 3rd layer) and 120, 40 for each neuron of the last layer

Comment: @a.br can you provide some sample data, sample code and an expected output. For example, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve